# What's so important about "Comptiq, october issue"?

Tags: outbreak-company

Shinichi jumps into a burning building in Episode 12 to save a copy of this "rare" issue. He also mentions it in the classroom before it burns down. Given this is a show with parody and otaku historical moments, what event is this referring to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This year's October issue of [Comptiq magazine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comptiq) was in extremely high demand because it came with a bonus artbook for [Kantai Collection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kantai_Collection), a web game featuring naval vessels as cute girls,<sup>1</sup> which is the latest mega-craze among otaku in Japan.<sup>2</sup> Apparently, tons of people were hoarding this issue in order to get multiple copies of the artbook.<sup>3</sup> The character on the right side of the cover is a parody of Kongou, a popular character from Kantai Collection.

Quite a timely joke, really.

---

Addendum: here are the covers of the parody of Comptiq ("Comptiqle"?) shown in the show and the actual Oct 2013 issue of Comptiq. (Click to view full-size.)

[image: Oct 2013 Comptiqle cover]
[image: Oct 2013 Comptiq cover]

---

## Notes

<sup>1</sup> Not to be confused with the *other* thing featuring naval vessels as cute girls, [Arpeggio of Blue Steel](http://myanimelist.net/anime/18893/Aoki_Hagane_no_Arpeggio:_Ars_Nova).

<sup>2</sup> [It's getting an anime soon](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/news/2013-09-26/kantai-collection-moe-card-battle-game-gets-anime-new-manga).

<sup>3</sup> See, for example, this piece: [Havoc Ensues Over Battleship Bishoujos](http://seventhstyle.com/2013/09/11/havoc-ensues-over-battleship-bishoujos/) (warning: SeventhStyle; NSFW). Because SeventhStyle is awful (but unfortunately the only English-language commentator on this I can find), here is some episodic commentary that mentions the joke (in Japanese): [some blog](http://anicobin.ldblog.jp/archives/35774503.html); [some other blog](http://animesokuhou777.blog.fc2.com/blog-entry-849.html).